# Finding encryption time for openssl in windows

Tags: openssl

I am trying to check the encryption time using the modes of operation for DES and AES using OpenSSL.
How can i check the time it takes to encrypt using OpenSSL on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OpenSSL application, you can simply write the following command:

```
openssl speed aes-128-cbc des-ede3
```

Or you can simply write a C-program to check the speed.

```
    AES_KEY             keyaes;
    DES_key_schedule    desk1;
    int                index;
    char srcbuf[16];
    char                dest[16];
    char                dest2[16];


//Set the keys.
memcpy (deskey, "abcdefgh", sizeof("abcdefg"));
memcpy (aeskey, "abcdefghijklmnop", sizeof("abcdefghijklmno"));

AES_set_decrypt_key((const unsigned char *)aeskey, 256, &keyaes2);
AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)aeskey, 256, &keyaes);
AES_set_decrypt_key((const unsigned char *)aeskey, 128, &keyaes128);
AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)aeskey, 128, &keyaes1282);

DES_key_sched ((const_DES_cblock *)deskey, &desk1);
DES_key_sched ((const_DES_cblock *)deskey, &desk2);
DES_key_sched ((const_DES_cblock *)deskey, &desk3);

memset(srcbuf, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

//Encrypt 64 times.
//AES
clock_t start = clock();
for(index = 0; index < 4096*4; ++index) {
    AES_encrypt ((const unsigned char *)srcbuf, (unsigned char *)dest, &keyaes);
}
clock_t stop = clock();

//DES
start = clock();
for(index = 0; index < 4096*4; ++index) {
    //AES  is encrypting 128 bytes, so it should also encrypt 128 bytes.
    DES_encrypt3 ((DES_LONG *)srcbuf, &desk1, &desk2, &desk3);
    DES_encrypt3 ((DES_LONG *)(srcbuf + sizeof(DES_LONG)), &desk1, &desk2, &desk3);
}
stop = clock();
```

Now, note the difference.

Comment: thanks but i was looking for a command to tell the time when am encrypting a particular file.
In Linux the time command tells you that.